# Is .NET support for Win32 Code Interop?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop, portable-executable

I need the InterOp Win32 code (unmanaged Win32 DLL's and EXE) with .NET. I need to call Win32 unmanaged code (DLL exported functions) at runtime knowing the data types in Win32 signatures and to pass data according to that type at runtime.

This is possible for COM, you can convert COM unmanaged code to managed assemblies using tlbimp.exe and use a reflection API to work with those managed types (unmanaged types converted to managed using tlbimp).

How can I get the same functionality in terms of Win32 in .NET framework?

I know MS provided an Export table reading API, but I couldn't find the exact API for interop of Win32 unmanaged code.

Comment: Please note the checkmarks next to the answers. This is how you can accept the answer that best addresses your question's needs. Also, please notice the up and down arrows. This is for up-voting good questions and answers and down-voting bad ones.

Comment: Up or down arrows what shows..?

Comment: Next to each question and answer is a number. It is how good users think it is. Above the number is a grey uparrow and a downarrow below it. If you find a question or answer helpful, please click the up arrow. If you find it particularly unhelpful, you can click the down arrow. When you ask a question, all answers will have a checkmark. For the answer that best addresses your question, you can click the checkmark to select it as the best answer. This also helps future viewers with a similar problem in the same way that these answers have helped you personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at http://www.pinvoke.net/

Using the services of [System.Runtime.InteropServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.aspx) you can interop with native Win32 code or any DLL that exports C type functions.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices enables you to get types from TypeLibs or others to extract out (e.g u can extract whole signatures defined in binary) but you need then REFLECTIONS to know the types at runtime and call those methods at runtime as well.

In case of Win32 we can extract types and signatures by reading Export table and headers of PE(Plain Win32 DLL) now here comes calling those methods at runtime same we did in case of COM using reflection. But reflection applies only managed assemblies. To me plain win32 DLL's can't be converted to managed assemblies.

Comment: No, you can't automagically generate the p/invoke declarations because native code does not have sufficient metadata. The link to pinvoke.net provides a huge about of ready made interop declarations for many of the Win32 APIs. You can follow the same pattern for non-Win32 API but you will need to do it manually.

Comment: To me PInvoke is just a call forwarder to unmanaged world and it does nothing else. No type checking at runtime it does.Is'nt?

Comment: @Usman, on the .NET side the types are very important. The interop services use the type information and various attributes to determine how to correctly marshat the data (arguments and return values) from the managed world to the unmanaged and back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

See [PInvoke on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx).